# How to run as administrator from java code(For mac osx)?

Tags: java, macos, runtime

I am trying to run a command on my mac os with java code :-

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

This is the command

```
sudo installer -pkg /Users/sumish/Desktop/aster.mpkg -target /Applications
```

When I run the command from terminal it prompts me for a administrator password

How can I do this from my code?

Answer (score 2):

I think your `java` process should be started with privileges in order for you to fork and launch another process which requires administrator rights.

So, the JVM which runs the code containing `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);` should be started using a `sudo java` command.